# Adding 2 versions of a gem in bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to add searchlogic 2.5.5 and rails 2.3.5 in my bundle. Here's my Gemfile

```
source :rubygems

gem "activerecord", ">= 2.3.5"
gem "prawn", "0.6.3"
gem "searchlogic", "2.5.5"
gem "declarative_authorization", "0.5.2"
gem "test-unit", "1.2.3"
gem "hoe", "1.5.1"
gem "rake", "0.8.7"
gem "rails", "2.3.5"
```

But whenever I try to execute

```
bundle install
```

it says

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
In Gemfile:
searchlogic (= 2.5.5) depends on
  activerecord (~> 2.3.11)

rails (= 2.3.5) depends on
  activerecord (2.3.5)
```

Is it possible to install 2 versions of the activerecord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm somewhat of a RoR newbie, so I might be wrong but I don't think so. I know with rvm you can make different gemsets, but that's not what you want.

Any reason you can't upgrade Rails or [downgrade searchlogic](http://rubygems.org/gems/searchlogic/versions/2.4.28) instead?

```
"rails", "~> 2.3.11"
```

or

```
gem "searchlogic", "2.4.28"
```

?

Comment: I guess I'll have to rewrite some code in order to downgrade or upgrade any gem but I guess that's the only option I have